# Read USDT transactions and balance on the Tron network(TRC20) with Java (Spring)

Tags: transactions, java, usdt

How can I read USDT transactions and balance on the Tron network(TRC20) with Java (Spring) for several addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.AccountResourceMessage;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.AccountNetMessage;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.BlockLimit;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.BlockList;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.NodeList;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.NumberMessage;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.TransactionList;
import org.tron.api.GrpcAPI.WitnessList;
import org.tron.api.WalletGrpc;
import org.tron.common.utils.ByteArray;
import org.tron.protos.Protocol.Block;
import org.tron.protos.Protocol.Transaction;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WalletGrpc.WalletBlockingStub stub = WalletGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

    // Connect to the Tron network
    ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("https://api.trongrid.io").usePlaintext().build();

    // Retrieve the transactions and balance for a specific address
    String address = "T address";
    ByteString addressBs = ByteString.copyFrom(ByteArray.fromHexString(address));
    AccountNetMessage accountNet = stub.getAccountNet(addressBs);
    AccountResourceMessage accountResource = stub.getAccountResource(addressBs);
    System.out.println("Free bandwidth: " + accountNet.getFreeNetUsed());
    System.out.println("Free bandwidth limit: " +
```